# Pattern for Firebase onAuthStateChanged and Navigation Guards - Quasar app

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, quasar-framework

I am facing an issue in my Quasar app with regards to browser refresh and Firebase authentication.

After a user logs in and then clicks on the browser refresh, then the `firebase.auth().currentUser` returns null (as this executes asynchronously). This means that when the `beforeEach` gets executed the `currentUser` is null and the user is prompted with the logon page. However I see that when the callback to `onAuthStateChanged` is getting invoked the user is getting set correctly.

Is there any pattern by which, in a Quasar app, the `onAuthStateChanged` can be used in navigation process so that existing user session is reused?

```js
// Vue-router => index.js
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  console.log('onAuthStateChanged Invoked => ' + user);
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  let currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser; 
  let requiresAuth = to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth);

  if (requiresAuth && !currentUser) {
    next('signin');
  } else {
    if (requiresAuth && currentUser.emailVerified === false) {
      next('signin');
    } else {
      next();
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

In your `main.js`, you should listen for `onAuthStateChange`.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'
import firebase from 'firebase'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

let app;
let config = {
  apiKey: "YOUR_API_KEY",
  authDomain: "YOUR_PROJECT_ID.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://YOUR_PROJECT_ID.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "YOUR_PROJECT_ID",
  storageBucket: "YOUR_PROJECT_ID.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "YOUR_MESSAGING_SEND_ID"
};

firebase.initializeApp(config)
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (!app) {
    /* eslint-disable no-new */
    app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      template: '<App/>',
      components: { App },
      router
    })
  }
});
```

We only initialize the app only when we are sure Firebase Auth object is ready to use.

Comment: Thanks. I had seen this proposal earlier. However with the Quasar app the initialization seems to be done by the framework. I came across a solution (in VueJS forums - https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vue-routes-firebase-auth-sync-problem/4470)  to wrap the  `firebase.auth().currentUser` with a Promise and then use the promise resolution to execute the logic within `beforeEach` which seems to be working.

Comment: This same code just sits in a Quasar boot file instead.

Answer (score 3):

I use the firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged function directly in my router guard like this:
I check if the route needs an authenticated user (optional) and then I load the currently logged in user and commit it in my Vuex store.
This way the currently logged in user is in my Vuex state before the route guard checks access. Otherwise, especially after a page reload, the user is not yet loaded and the guard redirects to the login page...

```
...

Router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {

  let requiresAuth = to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)

  // If route requires auth --> load auth state first from firebase
  if (requiresAuth) {

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {

      store.commit("user/SET_USER", user);

      let currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser
      store.commit("user/SET_USER_FULL", currentUser);

      user.getIdToken().then(token => {
        store.commit("user/SET_TOKEN", token)
      });

      if (!user) next('login')
      else next();
    });

  } else next()

})


export default Router
```

I use Quasar. And this code is in my router/index.js. Don't forget to import your store like this: import store from '../store'

Comment: Follwed your script. Just updated to Firebase 9 and now I can refresh my page.

Answer (score 0):

I refactored the whole router/auth thing again. Moved the code to ./boot/firebase.js.

```
export default async ({ router, store }) => {

// Here goes the firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig); 
// ...
const getCurrentUser = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((userFirebase) => {
        // Do some store stuff...
        store.commit("user/SET_USER", userFirebase);
        unsubscribe();
        resolve(userFirebase);
      }, reject);
    });
  }

  router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {

    const requiresAuth = to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth);

    if (requiresAuth && !await getCurrentUser()){
      next({ name: 'login' });
    } else if (!from.name) {
      // Load user also on a full page reload on pages which do not require auth...
      await getCurrentUser();
      next();
    } else {
      next();
    }
  });
```