# How to know if Firebase Auth is currently retrieving user?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

### Background

I am using `GoogleAuthProvider`, with the default `LOCAL` persistence.

When I navigate to the page, I do:

```js
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
firebase.auth().currentUser // this is always null
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  console.log("authStateChanged", user)
})
```

If the user is logged in, the callback is called once, with the user.

If the user is *not* logged in, the callback is also called once, with `null`.

This suggests I *could* wait until the first callback after navigating to the page to get the real login state before deciding what view to display, for instance. (I originally thought that it would not get called with `null`, and so I could end up waiting indefinitely)

### Question

Would that be idiomatic usage? Does it seem like it will be robust against updates to firebase? Where can I find this discussed in the official documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**2022 Edit:** in firebase web SDK 9, it's

```js
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";
const auth = getAuth();
export const isReady = new Promise(resolve => {
  const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (/* user */) => {
    resolve(/* user */)
    unsubscribe()
  })
})
```

P.S: The reason I don't resolve with the `user` is because it is available at `auth.currentUser`, while the promise would retain an outdated value.

---

Looking at similar questions such as [Pattern for Firebase onAuthStateChanged and Navigation Guards - Quasar app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50323975/2115619) it seems this is indeed the way it's done.

So I have come up with the following to differentiate the initial condition:

```js
export const isReady = new Promise(resolve => {
  const unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(() => {
    resolve()
    unsubscribe()
  })
})
```

I export this Promise from the module where I wrap firebase, so I can begin other initialization while waiting for an authoritative authentication state.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me instead. NB: For those user Quasar

```
export default async ({ app, router, store }) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      auth.authUser = user
      resolve()
      unsubscribe()
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: 1. why is it a function?
2. why is it async?
3. why are you destructuring an argument into bindings you won't use?
4. why are you setting auth.authUser (don't modify other people's objects, btw, ouch), if auth.currentUser is already set by Firebase?

Comment: the thing Is am using Quasar ( "https://quasar.dev/" )  auth.currentUser wasn't available on mobile(android) Build. So I added authUser to auth object. Now i can access the current user by calling auth.authUser

Comment: Are you sure you aren't just checking it before the promise resolves? (too early)

Comment: it's on my router.beforeEach. But i also noticed something , when i added "auth.authUser = user" both auth.authUser and auth.currentUser becomes available. But without adding "auth.authUser = user" or "auth.any_Available_Key = user"  auth.currentUser won't be available